# Open new tabs which opens PDF and then redirect to Index view but by controle

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a Control which creates a PDF file, then I would like to show it in a new tab, and same time this control redirects to Index.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: ok, it really long code..

Answer (score 0):

This is teh Controle

```
    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Edit(ByVal uSERINFO As USERINFO) As ActionResult

      db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.Documento).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.Badgenumber).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.Name).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.Gender).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.lastname).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.email).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.DEFAULTDEPTID).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.TITLE).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.CardNo).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.FPHONE).IsModified = True
        db.Entry(uSERINFOEdit).Property(Function(x) x.HIREDDAY).IsModified = True
        db.SaveChanges()

        Return ImprimirCarnetPDF(uSERINFOEdit.USERID)
    End Function
```

This the function which return PDF file

```
    Public Function ImprimirCarnetPDF(ID As String) As ActionResult
        Dim converter As New HtmlToPdf()
        Dim doc As PdfDocument
        Dim Uri = New Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
        Dim path = Uri.Scheme + "://" + Uri.Authority + "/WebForm1.aspx?usrid=" & ID
        doc = converter.ConvertUrl(path)
        Dim pdf As Byte() = doc.Save()
        doc.Close()
        Dim fileResult As FileResult = New FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf")
        fileResult.FileDownloadName = ID & "Document.pdf"
        Return fileResult
    End Function
```

Comment: Could you show View code? So we can see you how to call the action.

Comment: I did  see answer please